# ¿Como acceder a datos de un JSON con PHP?

Tags: php, json

Necesito alguna ayuda sobre este tema, lo he tratado como un array pero no me recorre necesito su ayuda.

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://servidor.com/json");
$prueba = json_decode($url,true);
$stdClass = json_decode(json_encode($url,true));

print_r ($prueba);
print_r ($stdClass);
```

PRIMER PINT

```
Array ( [consultarResponse] => Array ( [return] => Array ( [coResultado] => 0000 [datosPersona] => Array ( [apPrimer] => MERCEDES [apSegundo] => REYES [direccion] => AV.CESAR VALLEJO 1126 [estadoCivil] => SOLTERO [foto] => /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgA [prenombres] => HILMAR ALEXIS [restriccion] => NINGUNA [ubigeo] => LA LIBERTAD/TRUJILLO/TRUJILLO ) [deResultado] => Consulta realizada correctamente ) ) )
```

SEGUNDO PRINT

```
{"consultarResponse":{"return":{"coResultado":"0000","datosPersona":{"apPrimer":"MERCEDES","apSegundo":"REYES","direccion":"AV.CESAR VALLEJO 1126","estadoCivil":"SOLTERO","foto":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgA","prenombres":"HILMAR ALEXIS","restriccion":"NINGUNA","ubigeo":"LA LIBERTAD/TRUJILLO/TRUJILLO"},"deResultado":"Consulta realizada correctamente"}}}
```

Comment: No estaría claro que es lo que _"no me recorre"_ ¿Que es lo que estás intentando hacer? ¿Que datos necesitas obtener?

Comment: Hacer un foreach para recorrer el array

Comment: Necesito los datos apPrimer, apSegundo y etc

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código como has intentado acceder a dichos datos?

Comment: No puedo recorrerlo porque es un array dentro de otro array alguna sugerencia ahi mostré lo que imprime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a los siguientes comentarios:

> Hacer un foreach para recorrer el array
>   Necesito los datos apPrimer, apSegundo y etc

Como bien decis es un arreglo con arreglos dentro y para llegar al punto donde se encuentran los datos que necesitas, tenes que "*acceder*" hasta la "*profundidad*" donde se encuentran.

Otra forma de verlo sería:

```
consultarResponse
    |-> return
        |-> coResultado: 0000
        |-> datosPersona
        |   |-> apPrimer: MERCEDES
        |   |-> ...
        |-> deResultado: Consulta realizada correctamente
```

#### Solución:

Podrías lograrlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://servidor.com/json");
$result = json_decode($json, true);

$data = $result['consultarResponse']['return']['datosPersona'];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: En 2023, después de horas de búsqueda, logre dar solución a mi problema con tu respuesta. Muchas gracias